# Linked In refresh token permissions

Tags: linkedin-api

"**LinkedIn supports programmatic refresh tokens for a limited set of partners on a case-by-case basis.**"
 (cf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens?context=linkedin/context)

"**LinkedIn has introduced Refresh Tokens with OAuth 2.0.  This feature is currently available for a limited set of partners. It will be made GA in the near future.**"
(cf: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/Refresh-Tokens-with-OAuth-2)

What are the required steps to get the scope for refresh tokens' use ?
I can't modify the scopes myself on my app, I actually have the "Member Authorization" permission with scopes:

- r_emailaddress
- r_liteprofile
- w_member_social

It's actually the more permissive authorization available on linkedin developer platform.